# php intl extension not working on CentOS 7

Tags: php, centos, php-extension, php-ini

I want to install `php intl` extension on `CentOS 7` server but it's not working. when I run `php -m` command it does not show `intl` in list.

I have used `yum install php56-php-intl.x86_64` to install `intl` as I am using `php 5.6.13` version.

When I run `yum list php*intl` it shows me `php56-php-intl.x86_64` in installed versions list.

I have also added `extension=intl.so` in php.ini file still no luck.

Please help me to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: could you check if intl.so is in your extensions directory? did you restart your apache/nginx/what-ever-your-web-server is? Did you restart php-fpm if you use that?

Comment: After installation please restart your server whatever you use.and check if intl.so file is physically is there or not.